# Highcharts fadeIn produces plots larger than containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a container that has inside a `div` with 100% width and two small ones being 50% instead. A toggle button hide the big `div` and shows the small two, and vice versa.

html

```
<div class='container'>
    <button class="toggle">Split</button>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    position:relative;width:500px;height:300px;
}
.container div {
    position:absolute;height:240px;
}
.left {
    left:0px;width:50%;display:none;
}
.right {
    right:0px;width:50%;display:none;
}
.center {
    left:0px;right:0px;width:100%
}
```

Inside each of these three there is an Highcharts plot. When I run the code I see the big `div.center` first and it's fine. The when I switch to the small two (`.left` and `.rigth`) the inner `svg` of the plots are rendered much larger then the divs.

The strange thing is that as soon you resize the window (or in fiddle the 'result' tab) the plots become normal.

This is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/U3gNM/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, but still don't understand the problem.

To fix this I had to explicitly provide the width and height of the chart via:

```
 chart: {
        height: $('.left').height(),
        width: $('.left').width()
    }
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/U3gNM/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Full answer you can find [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#jquery-ui-tab). This is caused by not calculating width/height of the element in browser, when isn't displayed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. It's correct, chart size reverts to 600x400 pixels. Exactly what happened in my case. However I think pushing the container out of the view port seems an ugly workaround to me. I'd rather provide explicitly width and height like in my answer.

Comment: If you need responsive site, your solution won't be continuos - you will need to update charts width and height each time browser is resized. While solution where charts is visible, but out of view port, will handle it.

Comment: I don't get it, I'm not expert in this, so understand me. I provide dynamic width and height relative to the container. How responsive resizing is handled better?

Comment: For example you want chart with 50% of site width. With your solution, resizing browser won't change chart's width.

Comment: wouldn't that depend on the container having size relative to the window? As long as the chart has relative sizes (like in my answer) then it's a matter of working out how the container changes. Anyway, my pages in general have a toolbar and a dashboard with 900 px width centred in the browser window, and I don't need them to resize as the browser does.

Comment: As I said before, as long as you have fixed site - it's fine, but with responsive design like fluid columns it won't work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/U3gNM/3/ - Click "Split" then move separator between js code and charts. Observer background. I'm just adding my explanation in case someone else will need another answer.

Comment: oooh I see, I moved the separator in the combined viewed and it resizes the chart, I didn't know highchart automatically does that when you don't provide height and width. the question doesn't mention resizing needs but thanks at lot for your explanations.